# How to write csv file in windows

Tags: python, csv

I have a python code in that writing csv file.when i run the code in Ubuntu it is running when i run code in windows its creating error.

```
fp = open('result2.csv', 'a')
fp.write(post+'\t'+str(post_issue_list)+'\n')
fp.close()
```

UnicodeEncodeError:

> 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2764' is position 26: character maps to undefined>

```
fp.write(post+'\t'+str(post_issue_list)+'\n')
```

in this line error coming only when i run in windows,its fine in ubuntu

Comment: Why are you not using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: The error you are facing is due to encoding of the file. Try changing the encoding of the file to 'utf-8' or others.

Answer (score 0):

Add encoding parameter in open() and then write the file:

```
fp = open('result2.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
```